# Use of astropy.visualization hist() function instead of matplotlib hist() function

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, astropy

Can someone show me how to replace matplotlib hist() function with hist() function from astropy.visualization module from the following code:

```
Hist_SNR = plt.figure()
Hist_SNR, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)
ax[0].hist(data1['SNR'], bins=10, normed=False)
ax[1].hist(data2['SNR'], bins=10, normed=False)
ax[2].hist(data3['SNR'], bins=10, normed=False)
plt.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.visualization.hist.html#astropy.visualization.hist) you would replace

```
ax.hist(...)
```

by

```
astropy.visualization.hist(..., ax=ax)
```